# Regex in Oracle SQL Query - numbers and periods only

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle-apex

In an Oracle SQL query there is a field with the following content (example):

```
{"ID Card": 0.29333333333333333} or {"Speedtest": 0.8166666666666667}
```

Can I use RegEx, for example, to output the field in the query so that only the numbers and the period remain?

Example:

```
Select ID, CREATEDFORMAT, INSERT_TS, regexp_substr(SCORE, '[^0-9]') xSCORE FROM MYTABLE
```

But with the `[^ 0-9]` I only have the numbers without a point.

Comment: Is this JSON? If so, then string functions are not the best fit, you can use JSON functions instead.

Comment: So with (/[+-^?\d+((\.|\,)\d+)?/) I successfully read only the numbers and the point in the nline RegEx. But that doesn't work in Oracle

Comment: No it is Oracle SQL Query

Comment: Okay I found the solution. 
regexp_substr(SCORE, '[[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]{1,6}') xSCORE

Comment: Your regex solution would not work if the number was a whole number (an integer) with no decimal point or no numbers after the decimal.  Also, if the number was negative, your regex would return the number as a positive number.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle Database 12.1.0.2 or higher and the number you are trying to parse out is always in a JSON object, you can use the JSON_VALUE function to pull the information out.

#### Query

```
WITH
    sample_data
    AS
        (SELECT '{"ID Card": 0.29333333333333333}' AS sample_val FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '{"Speedtest": 0.8166666666666667}' FROM DUAL)
SELECT s.sample_val, json_value (s.sample_val, '$.*') AS number_val
  FROM sample_data s;
```

#### Result

```
                          SAMPLE_VAL             NUMBER_VAL
____________________________________ ______________________
{"ID Card": 0.29333333333333333}        0.29333333333333333
{"Speedtest": 0.8166666666666667}        0.8166666666666667
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(SCORE, '[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+')
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/gdQjwX/2)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [-+]?                    any character of: '-', '+' (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]*                   any character of: '0' to '9' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.?                      '.' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
```

Answer (score -1):

use: `REGEXP_SUBSTR (s.sample_val, '[+-]?[0-9]+[\.]?[0-9]+')`

see this demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=76c2b3be1d7d266f217d6b0541478c17

result:

```
SAMPLE_VAL                          NUMBER_VAL
----------------------------------  --------------------
{"ID Card": 0.29333333333333333}    0.29333333333333333
{"Speedtest": 0.8166666666666667}   0.8166666666666667
{"texts": 12.3456}                  12.3456
{"texts": -65}                      -65
```

This is a change to @Ryszard Czech's post.